# Дамп mysql создаётся с пустыми comment'ами

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dump

Пытаюсь перенести БД MySQL с локалхоста на сервер. На локалхосте сделал дамп базы через phpmyadmin, но при попытке импорта при выполнении запроса такого вида:

```
CREATE TABLE `actions` (
`aid` varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT
);
```

выдаётся ошибка:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3
```

Удалось выяснить, что это происходит из-за отсутствия параметров у `COMMENT`. Если добавить после него пустую строку `''`, то всё работает нормально.

Вопрос: как сделать дамп с правильным содержанием запроса?

Comment: Может там все же есть какие-либо галочки, отвечающие за всякие настройки экспорта, среди которых есть и та, что отвечает за комменты?.... попробуй обычный `mysqldump` через командную строку

Comment: Не нашёл таких.

Comment: так а что на счет `mysqldump` или другие программы ля работы с БД которые делают экспорт? а то может версия `phpmyadmin` глючит